# Android studio - unable to locate adb on ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio

I am trying to install Android Studio on my ubuntu 14.

Following [the official guide](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=studio) While the setup wizard is downloading the components, I get this message:

*....
   Updated ADB to support the USB devices declared in the SDK add-ons.
  Stopping ADB server failed (code -1).
  Unable to run 'adb': Cannot locate program "/home/muser/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb": error=2, No such file or directory.
  Starting ADB server failed (code -1).
....*

There are no Android folder under **/home/muser**

Why is it searching it in that directory?
How to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After installing Android Studio, just run the following command.

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb
```

[EDIT] - I installed Android Studio from [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/11/install-android-studio-ubuntu-14-04-ppa/)

Answer (score 1):

It's not `adb`. It is `android-tools-adb`.  Hence you need to use -

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb
```